# Why does the SVC classifier from SKLearn show incorrect classes_ order in the predict_proba output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, prediction

For a specific doument in the corpus, I need to know the probability for class 'pos'. I have created a simple example below:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# Creating a simple example train and testset
corpus = [
    "I love love.",
    "I hate hate.",
    "I very love.",
    "I very hate",
]

corpus_test = [
    "love love love",
    "hate hate hate",
]

# Create a TfidfVectorizer
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vect.fit_transform(corpus)
y = np.array(['pos', 'neg', 'pos', 'neg'])

X_test = vect.transform(corpus_test)
y_test = np.array(['pos', 'neg'])

clf = SVC(probability=True)
clf.fit(X, y)

print(f"classes_ = {clf.classes_}")
print(clf.predict_proba(X_test))   
print(f"\nPredictions:\n{clf.predict(X_test)}")
```

When I run this code, you can see that the order of `clf.classes_` is ['neg' 'pos'].

The probability in the first column (0) for the first document is 99.98%, which should correspond to class 'neg' according to `clf.classes_`. However, the prediction of this first document is 'pos'. So, the order of `clf.classes_` does not correspond with the column order in the output of `clf.predict_proba()` when using the SVC classifier.

When I replace the SVC classifier `clf = SVC(probability=True)` with the MultinomialNB classifier `clf = MultinomialNB()` , the issue is fixed and the order of `clf.classes_` does correspond with the order of `clf.predict_proba()` .

Does anyone know why the order of the columns in `clf.predict_proba()` do not correspond with the order of `clf.classes_` while using the SVC classifier?